How to implement limited visibility for Google maps in Flutter and Dart?
I am trying to implement a Google Maps project in Flutter and Dart and within this project i want to implement a fog of war concept to Google Maps. So, when the user is on the map, initially they can only see part of the map and to unlock more of the map, they have to explore those areas to unlock the visibility.
I have tried looking up videos on how to implement this but none of the videos show how to implement this in flutter. I have also tried using ChatGPT and searching on the web but with no success.

You could try to place your GoogleMap into a Stack. Then, you could put another widget into your stack above (wrapped with an IgnorePointer widget to ignore the gesture events and allow the map below to capture them.
Then, with the GoogleMap widget's onCameraMove function (which will be invoked every time the camera position changes and includes details about the bearing, Lat+Lon, tilt, and zoom of the camera), you can do some logic to determine what is shown by the map below and then adjust your widget atop the map in the stack (maybe with a CustomPainter) to draw such that it covers undiscovered parts of the map.
You would need to keep track of the areas discovered by the user together with having some logic to determine what positions are actually visible in the map viewport given the camera details.
